# How to execute a set of code before and after controller tests written using PlaySpecification?

Tags: scala, playframework, cassandra

```
class UserControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification {
      "User Controller" should {
        "successfully register a new user." in {
          implicit val app = FakeApplication()

          running(app) {
            val response = route(FakeRequest(
              Helpers.POST,
              com.qburst.omnia.api.controllers.routes.UserController.signUp().url,
              FakeHeaders(Seq(CONTENT_TYPE -> Seq("application/json"))),
              Json.obj("email" -> "user@test.com",
                "password" -> "testpassword"))).get
            status(response) must equalTo(OK)
            contentType(response) must beSome("application/json")
            charset(response) must beSome("utf-8")
            val responseNode = Json.parse(contentAsString(response))
            (responseNode \ "status").as[Int] must equalTo(1)
          }
        }
      }
}
```

I would like to create Cassandra keyspace before executing a set of such tests, and delete Cassandra keyspace after executing the test. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just noticed that specs2 library already has 'BeforeAfterAll' trait that lets you do it. Try something like below:

```
import org.specs2.specification.BeforeAfterAll

class UserControllerSpec extends PlaySpecification with BeforeAfterAll{

      override def beforeAll(): Unit = //Initialize Cassandra here

      override def afterAll(): Unit = //Release Cassandra here

      "User Controller" should {
        "successfully register a new user." in {
          implicit val app = FakeApplication()

          running(app) {
            val response = route(FakeRequest(
              Helpers.POST,
              com.qburst.omnia.api.controllers.routes.UserController.signUp().url,
              FakeHeaders(Seq(CONTENT_TYPE -> Seq("application/json"))),
              Json.obj("email" -> "user@test.com",
                "password" -> "testpassword"))).get
            status(response) must equalTo(OK)
            contentType(response) must beSome("application/json")
            charset(response) must beSome("utf-8")
            val responseNode = Json.parse(contentAsString(response))
            (responseNode \ "status").as[Int] must equalTo(1)
          }
        }
      }
}
```

You can find it in the latest version of specs2 library. I am not sure which version it was added in.

Answer (score 0):

quick update:

if you need to run this on **playframework 2.6.x**
you can use

```
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
class UserControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfterAll{

override def beforeAll(): Unit = //code to run before all tests starts
override def afterAll(): Unit = //code to run after all tests finishes

"User Controller" should {
        "successfully register a new user." in {
         //blabla
        }
 }

}
```

I hope this helps someone ;)